# How do I bring back 'Editor' function in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have taken over the management of a WordPress site, but notice that there is no "Editor" option in 'Appearance' or 'Plugins' - and I want it back!

`wp-config` contains the following:

```
define(‘DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT’, false);
```

There is no plugin running that can disable this, how else can I bring back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Run the  your_domain/wp-admin/plugin-editor.php and confirm, is it work or not.

This will disable editor in theme and plugins, I use this code in wp-config.php

```
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

read this you can take an idea.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-theme-and-plugin-editors-from-wordpress-admin-panel/

And also check plugins which your used , because there plugin options to disable editor.

also check this 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

eg.

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
  remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );                    //Jetpack* 
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
  remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
  remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
  remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @ssk8323, but it is already disabled (somehow), I want to enable the Editor!

Comment: OK, /wp-admin/plugin-editor.php shows 
"Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.", so that confirms that I haven't got access.  I can't see 'remove_menu_page' in function.php, is that where it is supposed to be?

Comment: @bdstl eg. wp-config-file-editor plugin, find the  "DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT" text in your project, you can find any replacement options . you cant find that code in your function.php its an example and a link

Comment: Now this is interesting @ssk8323. When I launched the wp-config-file-editor plugin, 'Disable Plugin & Theme Editor' was checked, I unchecked it, clicked 'Save', then 'Update' and 'Done'.  When it goes back into  wp-config-file-editor plugin, 'Disable Plugin & Theme Editor' is checked again!!!!  BTW, when I click on 'Raw Editing' "DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT" isn't there

Comment: @bdstl - no I gave you an example, it said there are plugin also disable the editors. Remove the plugin and then find the "DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT" code inside your project, and check is it enable or not,

Comment: "DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT" code is now not in my wp-config.php file and the 'Editor' still isn't showing.  I've added 'define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', false );' and it now working :-) Thanks